# Link error "ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors."

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors

I'm still learing c++ and was following an example from my book. I basically copied their code and added the include and namespace. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Date{
  int y,m,d;
public:
  Date(int y, int m, int d);
  int month(){return m;}
  int day(){return d;}
  int year(){return y;}
};

int main(){
  Date b{1970,12,30};
cout<< b.month()<< '\n';
}
```

Trying to compile with g++ -std=c++11 -o test2 test2.cc

Error:

```
Date::Date(int, int, int)           /var/tmp//ccGuivAs.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to main    
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to provide the implementation of `Date`s constructor somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date(int y, int m, int d);
```

The error message is signaling (in an admittedly unclear way) that there's no definition for `Date`. It's declared, but not defined. You didn't specify what the constructor *does*.

```
Date(int y, int m, int d) {
    this->y = y;
    this->m = m;
    this->d = d;
}
```

Or, better, using [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) syntax:

```
Date(int y, int m, int d): y(y), m(m), d(d) { }
```

Comment: I added : y(y), m(m), d(d) { } to my Date(int y, int m, int d): as suggested and I'm no longer getting error (YAY!). But it isn't printing out anything in main now. It feels like I'm stuck in my class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add implementation (definition) of constructor

```
Date(int y, int m, int d);
```

At the moment there is only a declaration found in your `Date` class and such a situation results in

> undefined reference to `Date::Date(int, int, int)' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

http://ideone.com/wMgbKX

Answer (score 0):

You *declared* the `Date::Date` constructor, but never *defined* it.

Your declaration is a promise to the compiler that the constructor `Date::Date` will be defined somewhere. But you never actually provided a definition. That is what's causing the error.

You can provide a definition right there, inside the class definition, like you did with other member functions. Or you can provide a definition outside the class. It is up to you. But a definition has to be provided somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `Date::Date(int, int, int)` (i.e. the `Date` constructor) somewhere, as explicitly stated by your compiler.
You could do that by adding a body to it, like for its `month`, `day` and `year` methods, or outside of the class.